# Jquery to copy values from table td to input

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table that displays all my clients information. I want to be able to take the clientid column and copy all the id's into a input box. The TD has a unique ID which is 'clientid'. If I try to copy the text to the input it just gets the first value in the table not all of them.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="clientid">
       45
    </td>
    <td>
       John Salsasauce
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="clientid">
       53
    </td>
    <td>
       Andrew Foobaloba
    </td>
  </tr>
// more here...
</table>
```

This is the jQuery I am using but it only gets the first instance of `#clientid` value.

```
$("button#copybutton").click(function(){
   $("textarea#copy").val($("#clientid").text()); 
});
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to extract the values from multiple table cells and concatentate them together for display within a single input? Also, if you've repeated the same id on each row that's not valid - try using a class instead.

Comment: One tip: If you are specifying the ID, you don't need to specify the element type too. So, `#copybutton` instead of `button#copybutton`. As nnnnnn says, you also can't duplicate IDs

Comment: Can you post the whole table, or at least a few records?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes thanks. I now know not to duplicate ID's!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use class (say myclass)

```
   $("textarea#copy").val( $(".myclass").map(function(){
      return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(", ") );
```